# Deduce template argument for size of initializer list

Tags: c++, c++14, initializer-list, template-argument-deduction

I have the following (not compilable) code:

```
template< size_t N >
void foo( std::array<int, N> )
{
  // Code, where "N" is used.
}

int main()
{
  foo( { 1,2 } );
}
```

Here, I want to pass an arbitrary number of `int`s to a function `foo` -- for convenience, I will use the `std::initializer_list` notation.
I tried to use an `std::array` to aggregate the `int`s (as shown in the code above), however, the compiler can not deduce the array size since the `int`s are passed as an `std::initializer_list`.

Using an `std::initializer_list` instead of an `std::array` also does not solve the problem since (in contrast to `std::array`) the size of the `std::initializer_list` is not captured as template argument.

Does anyone know which data structure can be used so that the `int`s can be passed by using the `std::initializer_list` notation and without passing the template argument `N` of `foo` explicitly?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `std::initializer_list::size` is a constexpr function since c++14. Won't that do?

Comment: @StoryTeller No, because the object argument must be `constexpr`, and function parameters cannot be `constexpr`.

Comment: Would calling `foo(1,2)` (for any number of args) work for you?

Comment: @Columbo, are you sure? `constexpr` functions don't seem feasible if arguments to them cannot be `consexpr`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well... strictly speaking, the object argument need not be `constexpr` if the body doesn't use `this` accordingly, but we cannot know if it does. To answer your question: *parameters* cannot be `constexpr`, but we could have other scenarios.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [core issue 1591](http://wg21.link/cwg1591), you can use

```
template <std::size_t N>
void foo( int const (&arr)[N] )
{
  // Code, where "N" is used.
}

foo({1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- the solution works! Can you please help me to understand what `int const (&arr)[N]` is: an array? Moreover, using `int (&arr)[N]` without `const` does not work -- can you please help me to understand why?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert 1) `int const (&arr)[N]` is a const reference to an array. 2) Are you aware that temporaries can be bound to const references, but not non-const references? Well, we're creating an array temporary and bind it to the reference, which is not permitted for non-const references.

Comment: I see, thank you. One problem remains: the case of an empty initializer list should also be possible (i.e. `N==0`) which currently causes a compiler error. Do you see any solution?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert What about adding `void foo (int) {/*code for N=0*/}`

Comment: If there is no simple implementation for using an empty array (i.e., `{}`), I will use `void foo ()` -- thank you very much for the great tips.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent for templated classes and their constructor (e.g. `Klass k({1,2,3})` would specialize template Klass<int N>)

Comment: @Osman-pasha [Are you looking for deduction guides](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XBe8ExpKRBSYFEuh)?

Comment: @Columbo yes, thank you. I did not even know these things exist.

Answer (score 3):

If using an initializer list is not a must, you can use variadic template parameter packs:

```
template<size_t S>
void foo_impl(array<int, S> const&)
{
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}

template<typename... Vals>
auto foo(Vals&&... vals) {
    foo_impl<sizeof...(vals)>({ std::forward<Vals>(vals)... });
}
```

you'd call it as follows:

```
foo(1,2,3,4,5);
```

This defers common type checks until the initialization point of `std::array` (unless you add some admittedly ugly asserts), so you probably should prefer Columbo's answer.